# How to print from <form action>?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code in post.php:

```
    <?php
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

if (isset($_GET['debug'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
} else {
    echo stripslashes($_POST['editor']) ;
}
```

And at the main page there is a form button that calls post.php with a post action and export everything within a div.
How can  configure it to print the exported page when I click that form button?

AJAX,
PHP,
JQUERY,
JAVASCRIPT
???

Comment: Just put a [`<script>window.print()</script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print) in the export page.

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping this. Aren't you doing that now?

Comment: Sorry, I can't put anything on the export page, I need that on the main page. So Suman Bogati, just that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain anything from a submitted form (method=post) in PHP, there is the global `$_POST` as you have discovered. The keys (debug, editor) in that array correspond to the name attributes of select, textarea and input fields from the submitted form. They are not the same as jQuery selectors, meaning you can not *export everything from a div* unless you use JavaScript to set the value attribute of an input to the content of that div.

crude example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="post"]').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        console.log('click');
        $('form').append(
            $('<input name=div type=hidden>').val($('div').html())
        );

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').prepend('SENDING<br>');
            $('form').submit();
        }, 333);
    });
}
);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="moo.php">
<textarea name="summary" cols=80 rows=3>
Zuma is a big man
</textarea>
<br>

<input type="text" name="what" value="zuma?">
<br>

<select id="" name="">
<option value="55">schfifty five</option>
<option value="2">doo</option>

</select>
<br>

<input type="submit" name="post" value="send">
</form>
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>

<div> random stuff <span> foobar </span>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a javascript that takes care of the post form, what I wonder now is what is moo.php :/

Comment: Are you serious? It's the example php-file in the answer.

Comment: THe javascript is part from the wysiwyg editor, it's not in this post as not even I know where it is.

Comment: Then you need to extract the information from the editor, or submit the *textarea* from that wsywig editor.

Comment: Hmm, the form works, when you click it, it exports the page, I just like to have an option to open a print window when you click it. I tried adding a print button on the exported page, but when you click it, it wont print the images or background, even after enabling then in the printing options, on the other hand, the print button works on the main page, but the layout gets broken.